# onTouchListener in Listview without breaking styling or touch

Tags: android, listview

I have been trying to style some elements of a ListView. Mainly, on top of the color & background made by selectors, I would like to also change the font of the pressed item. This is not doable with a selector, so I have to do this by code.
I have tried many approaches, with no success.

simplified sample code to illustrate the issue :

in the adapter of the listview :

```
getView(..) {
if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout);
   viewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
   ...
   convertView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
   }
}

private class  MyTouchListener implements onTouchListener {

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
..
switch (maskedAction) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    textView.setTypeface(BOLD);
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    textView.setTypeface(NORMAL); 
    break;
    }
    return false; //// PROBLEM
}
```

Now, my issue is that if my touch listener returns false for the pointer down event, it means I did not consume the event, so I don't receive the subsequent event (move, up, ..). So the textview is stuck in the BOLD font.
If I return true for the onDown event, the framework considers that the event has already been handled for the view, so it ignores the selectors in my xml. Annoying, but I could always do all the styling in the code, even if it means losing the advantage of selectors for the proprieties that can use it. It also means that the item does not receive the click event, which is a deal breaker.
So, I am in a dead end here. I have tried many alternatives ways to do this (custom view which calls both my listener and the default one, different returns values, ...) with no success.
Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out :
By design, this is not doable with an `OnTouchListener`. However, there are several other options.
One is to override `dispatchTouchEvent` or `onInterceptTouchEvent` in the parent `ViewGroup`.
Another is to override `onCreateDrawableState`.
Since I was already overloading this method (in order to create new states), I opted for that one :

```
@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    {...}
    if (mListener != null) {
        if (isPressed() != isPressed) {
            isPressed = isPressed();
            mListener.onPressedStateChange(isPressed);
        }
    }
    return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
}

public interface PressedStateListener {

    public void onPressedStateChange(boolean isPressed);
}

PressedStateListener mListener;

public void setOnPressedStateChangedListener(PressedStateListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

in the viewholder :

```
 private class DropDownOnPressedStateChangedListener implements PressedStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onPressedStateChange(boolean isPressed) {
        if (isPressed) {
            getText().setTypeface(MEDIUM_TYPEFACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
        } else {
            getText().setTypeface(REGULAR_TYPEFACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
    }
```

in the adapter :

```
  if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(ENTRY_RESOURCE_ID, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new HeaderDropDownViewHolder(view);
        ((CustomLayout)view).setOnPressedStateChangedListener(viewHolder.getOnListener());
```

That way I have a clean implementation that allows me to edit any view property when it is pressed or not without any conflict with its existing customization or behavior.